# How to split string by "-" for one item in a list?

Tags: python, string

I have a list with one item that I need to split by "-" to access the last segment of data:

```
a = ['1-35-047-13-6299\t1\n']
```

Normally, I would do this by using the following call:

```
test = a.split("-")
```

However, this yields the following error

```
>>> a = ['1-35-047-13-6299\t1\n']
>>> a
['1-35-047-13-6299\t1\n']
>>> test = a.split("-")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
>>>
```

How can I get at the last segment of data in the list item e.g. "6299\t1\n" using the split method?

Answer (score 4):

```
test = a[0].split('-')[-1]
print test
```

Comment: `a[0].rsplit("-",1)[1]` might be worth mentioning as well .. +1 all the same

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two problems here. For one thing, as the error message says `split` expects a string rather than a list, but `a` is a list of strings rather than a string. So `split` needs `a[0]` for this specific case, or in general something you can trust to be a string.

Then there's the need to split off just the rightmost element.  That's what `rsplit` is for, probably with the parameter that limits the number of splits. So bottom line you want something like:

```
test = a[0].rsplit('-',1)[1]
```

Even that will fail if your input string does not contain a `-` character - either capturing the whole output of `rsplit` and checking its length or using reverse indexing into its output would work to guard against that case.

Answer (score 0):

the traceback show that :`'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

'String' object has the attribute 'split',
you can use `a[i].split('-')`